# React admin app bar name and photo shows null

Tags: react-admin

My react-admin project has been updated to lattest version. Now I can see this image in my AppBar. How can I show right username and photo correctly.

[Appbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhBRx.png)

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is deep in the doc and happened in the `authProvider`:

```
// in src/authProvider.js
const authProvider = {
    login: ({ username, password }) => { /* ... */ },
    checkError: (error) => { /* ... */ },
    checkAuth: () => { /* ... */ },
    logout: () => { /* ... */ },
    getIdentity: () => {
        try {
            const { id, fullName, avatar } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
            return Promise.resolve({ id, fullName, avatar });
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
    // ...
};

export default authProvider;
```

ref: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#user-identity